# Why do we have to include the pairs $(b, b)$ and $(c, c)$ in the transitive closure?

Tags: relations

The problem is:

> Find the reflexive, symmetric and the transitive closure of the
>   following relation:
>
> $R = \{ (a, a), (a, b), (b, c), (c, b)\}$
>
> on the set of elements $A = \{a, b, c\}$

Finding the reflexive and the symmetric closure for $R$ was quite trivial, but I am a little bit confused with why *we have to include the pairs $(b, b)$ and $(c, c)$ in the following transitive closure*:

$T_R = \{(a, a), (a, b), (b, c), (c, b), (a, c), (b, b), (c, c)\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $(b,c)\in R$ and $(c, b)\in R,\;$ so for transitive closure, we need $\,(b, b)\in T_R.$

Similarly, for transitive closure, $(c, b)\in R$ and $(b, c)\in R\,$ require that $(c, c) \in T_R$.